# unexpected assignment for function within Map()

Tags: r, function

A script that I have been using suddenly fails due to unexpected assignment. Any ideas what the reason could be?

```
  > head(datalist[[1]])
                                                    V1            V2       V3      V4      V5
1                                         UNCLASSIFIED            -1 99.81236       - 5800696
2                                          k__Bacteria             2  0.18764 0.00025     650
3                        k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria      2|201174  0.16644 0.00023     571
4                        k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria        2|1224  0.02120   3e-05      79
5      k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria 2|201174|1760  0.16644 0.00023     571
6 k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria   2|1224|1236  0.02120   3e-05      7
```

Function:

```
dfs.bac <- Map(function(x, nm) { names(x)[[names(x) == "V5"] <- nm; x[[, c("V1", nm)]; }, datalist, names(datalist))
```

Error:

```
 Error: unexpected assignment in "dfs.bac <- Map(function(x, nm) { names(x)[[names(x) == "V5"] <-"
```

Comment: Is the problem that I write it on one line?

Comment: It looks you have a couple of extra `[`s. In two occasions, you use the double bracket, but close with a single bracket.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typo: you open with two brackets `[[` but close with only one. Replace all `[[` with `[` in that code and it works.

(Additionally, for sample data, I assigned a name to `datalist`.)

```r
# datalist <- ... # from the question
# names(datalist) <- "quux"
datalist <- list(quux = structure(list(V1 = c("UNCLASSIFIED", "k__Bacteria", "k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria", "k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria", "k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria", "k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria"), V2 = c("-1", "2", "2|201174", "2|1224", "2|201174|1760", "2|1224|1236"), V3 = c(99.81236, 0.18764, 0.16644, 0.0212, 0.16644, 0.0212), V4 = c("-", "0.00025", "0.00023", "3e-05", "0.00023", "3e-05"), V5 = c(5800696L, 650L, 571L, 79L, 571L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
dfs.bac <- Map(function(x, nm) { names(x)[names(x) == "V5"] <- nm; x[, c("V1", nm)]; }, datalist, names(datalist))
dfs.bac
# $quux
#                                                     V1    quux
# 1                                         UNCLASSIFIED 5800696
# 2                                          k__Bacteria     650
# 3                        k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria     571
# 4                        k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria      79
# 5      k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria     571
# 6 k__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria       7
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling right-hand side functions such as `subset` to select needed columns and `setNames` to rename columns, streamlined with new pipe, `|>`, to avoid braces and brackets:

```r
dfs.bac <- Map(
    function(x, nm) subset(x, select = c(V1, V5)) |> setNames("V1", nm),
    datalist,
    names(datalist)
)
```